# How can I create PLAN_TABLE in db2 Z/OS

Tags: sql-execution-plan, db2-zos

I want to log events in plan table.

```
EXPLAIN PLAN SET QUERYNO = 10
FOR select id,name from t_test;
```

when I try to create plan it shows below error.

> THE REQUIRED EXPLANATION TABLE IBMUSER.PLAN_TABLE DOES NOT EXIST. 
>   SQLCODE=-219, SQLSTATE=42704, DRIVER=4.18.60"

How I can create the plan_table or it inbuilt.

Comment: The [manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/usrtab/src/tpc/db2z_plantable.html) claims that "*You can find a sample CREATE TABLE statement for each EXPLAIN table in member DSNTESC of the prefix.SDSNSAMP library.*"

Comment: There is any tool help me to log all sql queries  with host name or ip accessing my db

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to accomplish this.

1. If you are using Data Studio, it can create the explain tables for you.
2. You can utilize Db2 supplied stored procedure ADMIN_EXPLAIN_MAINT to create and maintain the explain tables in the correct format.  The DB2 command line processor can be executed through Unix Systems Services to call the stored procedure.  Here is an example call - using DBEXPL as the database (you should change to a database you can create objects in).

   CALL ADMIN_EXPLAIN_MAINT ('RUN', 'CREATE', 'NO', 'ALL', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'DBEXPL', NULL, NULL, 'BP1', 'BP8K1', 'BP16K1', 'BP32K1', 'BP1', 'BP1', 'BP8K1', 'BP16K1', 'BP32K1',?,?)#
3. Alternately, DDL to create the explain tables is also in .SDSNSAMP(DSNTESC).

For further reference, here is a link to the Db2 documentation of this stored procedure:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_12.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sp_adminexplainmaint.html